# open all word docs in a folder and copy and paste contents back to excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have two versions of code that i have tried that are slightly different and neither works unfortunately. I need some help figuring out why and how to do what i need to do thanks

The first bit of code somehow immediately ends the loop and doesn't meet the initial conditional expression though I am not sure why because it should call all .docx files in that folder

the second bit of code throws an error Invalid Use of Property with this line Set wApp.Visible = True and I do not know why

First version

```
Dim folder As String
Dim doc As Document

folder = "G:\GAV\Educational On Assignment Folder\On Assignment Tour Reports\2019\On Tour Questionnaire"
file = Dir(folder & "*.dox*")
r = 1

Do While Len(file) < 0
    Set doc = Documents.Open(Filename:=folder & file)
    ActiveDocument.Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks("Reports Excel").Activate
    Cells(1, r).Paste
    doc.Close
    r = r + 1
    file = Dire
Loop
```

Second version

```
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim mySource As Object
Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set mySource = obj.getfolder("G:\GAV\Educational On Assignment Folder\On Assignment Tour Reports\2019\On Tour Questionnaire")

For Each file In mySource.Files(Word.Application)
    If Len(file.Name) > 0 And InStr(1, file.Name, "$") = 0 Then
    Set wApp.Visible = True
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(muSource & "\" & file.Name, , ReadOnly)
    ActiveDocument.Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks("Reports Excel").Activate
    Cells(1, r).Paste
    doc.Close
    r = r + 1
    wApp.Quit
    Set wApp = Nothing
    End If
Next file
```

I need Excel to open each file in the folder, copy its entire contents and paste to a column in Excel. should be simple

Comment: "\*.dox\*"  - can't think of any Word file extensions this would match.  Do you mean "*.doc\*" ?

Comment: wApp.Visible fails because there's not actually anything there. You never opened a new instance of Word.  `Set wApp = New Word.Application`

Comment: damnit! i checked that word like 10 times! yea, thats what i mean. thank you both

Comment: so neither of those fixes worked for their respective codes. the same things still happen as i described before

Comment: why would you want to check if the length of the file name is < 0 in the first version?  `Do While Len(file) < 0`